# Некорректная работа import/export js

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, модули

Собираю скрипты webpack'ом, использую модули. Давно не писал код и некоторые моменты подзабыл. Раньше делал вот так в модулях: `function clock() { // code } module.exports = clock;` и вот так в index.js: `$(function() { let clock = require('./modules/clock.js')); clock(); });`.
Сейчас решил делать все через import/export es6. Но почему-то модули не работают когда их подключаю одним образом и работают частично когда подключаю другим образом, хотя в готовом файле все модули скомпилированы. Есть три модуля: clock.js, button.js и list.js. Когда вызван первым модуль clock(), идущий за ним модуль работает, а третий подключенный не работает. Но если вызвать первым любой другой модуль, то модуль часов перестает работать. А если вызвать первыми два модуля button() и list(), то будет работать первый подключенный из них. Вообщем я не понимаю что я упустил и почему модули ведут себя таким образом.
Ссылка на код: [import/export](https://github.com/NikitaKurtasov/import-export)

Comment: Так может дело вовсе не в модулях, обернуть все функции в `try/catch` и посмотреть нет ли ошибки.

Comment: Да, вы правы, нашел пару ошибок. Спасибо